# Error when trying to get the ViewChild from unit test using Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, parent-child

I am trying to do a unit test for the following component

```
   
  // Emisión de evento de padre a hijo (cargar contactos)
  @ViewChild(ContactosComponent) contactosComponent!: ContactosComponent;

  // Emisión de evento de padre a hijo (cargar nivel)
  @ViewChild(NivelComponent) nivelComponent!: NivelComponent;

   /**
   * Método para realizar peticiones al backend cuando se necesite cargar data en una pestaña especifica
   * @param event: TabViewChangeEvent
   */
  handleChange(event: TabViewChangeEvent): void {
    switch (event.index) {
      /** Pestaña Configuración */ 
      case 1:
        // Cargar configuracion
        break;
      /** Pestaña Contactos */ 
      case 2:
        // Limpiar tabla contactos
        this.contactosComponent.resetTablaContacto();
        if ( this.empresaRow && this.guarderiaRow ) {
          this.contactosComponent.loadContactos(this.empresaRow.id, this.guarderiaRow.id);
        }
        break;
      /** Pestaña Nivel */ 
      case 3:
        // Limpiar tabla niveles
        this.nivelComponent.resetTablaNivel();
        if ( this.empresaRow && this.guarderiaRow ) {
          this.nivelComponent.loadNiveles(this.empresaRow.id, this.guarderiaRow.id);
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

I am using the following component spec.ts to do the test

```
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<GuarderiasComponent>;
  let component: GuarderiasComponent;
  let contactosComponent: ContactosComponent;
  let nivelComponent: NivelComponent;
  let dataTableNivelComponent: DataTableNivelComponent;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync (() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ConfirmDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        GuarderiasComponent, 
        NivelComponent,
        ContactosComponent
      ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GuarderiasComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  
    // Crear e inyectar el componente ContactosComponent
    const contactosFixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactosComponent);
    contactosComponent = contactosFixture.componentInstance;
    component.contactosComponent = contactosComponent;
  
    // Crear e inyectar el componente NivelComponent
    const nivelFixture = TestBed.createComponent(NivelComponent);
    nivelComponent = nivelFixture.componentInstance;
    component.nivelComponent = nivelComponent;
    
    // Crear e inyectar el componente NivelComponent
    const nivelDataTableFixture = TestBed.createComponent(DataTableNivelComponent);
    dataTableNivelComponent = nivelFixture.componentInstance.dataTableNivelComponent;
    nivelComponent.dataTableNivelComponent = dataTableNivelComponent;
    
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('debería limpiar la tabla de niveles y cargar niveles en el cambio a la pestaña de Nivel', () => {
    const event: TabViewChangeEvent = { index: 3 } as TabViewChangeEvent;
    
    spyOn(nivelComponent, 'resetTablaNivel');
    spyOn(nivelComponent, 'loadNiveles');
    spyOn(dataTableNivelComponent, 'onRowUnselect');

    component.empresaRow = empresa;
    component.guarderiaRow = guarderia;

    component.handleChange(event);

    expect(nivelComponent.resetTablaNivel).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

Here I am trying to create the components on which it depends as levelComponent and contactsComponent that the function is executed respectively, in the case of it I am testing only the case that calls levelsComponents.

Getting an error like this when I run said test since the child components are as undefined

````
            at NivelComponent.resetTablaNivel (src/app/modules/configuration/sub-modules/guarderia/guarderias/pages/nivel/nivel.component.ts:59:34)
            at GuarderiasComponent.handleChange (src/app/modules/configuration/sub-modules/guarderia/guarderias/pages/guarderias/guarderias.component.ts:186:29)
            at UserContext.apply (src/app/modules/configuration/sub-modules/guarderia/guarderias/pages/guarderias/guarderias-childs.component.spec.ts:140:15) ```


I have been able to notice that it is also requiring the dataTable component but I declare this component and do the spyOn but it is never read, I need help to be able to check the function of the ts without errors
````

Comment: I was able to get out of this error, I needed to place the import of the DataTable components in configureTestingModule.

But I got an extra intermittent error when making the call
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resetTablaNivel') Already with the components called, it is intermittent because in every 1 of 10 calls it appears